# Can´t find new Bluetooth LE GATT APIs for UWP

Tags: uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to try the new Bluetooth LE GATT APIs in Windows 10 in an UWP application but I can't find the new APIs that the documentation mentions.

I am looking at the documentation here: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/gatt-server

```
Guid myGuid = Guid.Parse("34B1CF4D-1069-4AD6-89B6-E161D79BE4D0");
GattUuid uuid = GattUuid.FromUuid(myGuid);
...
GattServiceProviderResult result = await GattServiceProvider.CreateAsync(
            GattUuid.FromUuid(uuid),
            GattServiceType.Primary);

if (result.Error == BluetoothError.Success)
{
    serviceProvider = result.ServiceProvider;
    // 
}
...
_readCharacteristic = await serviceProvider.CreateCharacteristicAsync(
           GattUuid.FromUuid(uuid1),
           ReadParameters
           );
```

I can´t find the GattUuid class, any method in GattServiceProvider that matches the parameters GattServiceProvider.CreateAsync(GattUuid.FromUuid(uuid), GattServiceType.Primary); or the CreateCharacteristicAsync method.

I am using Visual Studio Professional 2017 Version 15.1 (26403.3), 
I have installed Windows 10 SDK (10.0.15063.0), 
I created a blank UWP Application with target version and min version set to Windows 10 Creators Update (10.0;Build 15063)

Comment: This issue is reported. The related team is investigating it.

Comment: also reported at https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-uwp/issues/63

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs need to be updated, as that class was removed.

GattServiceProvider.CreateAsync simply takes a GUID now, and there is a BluetoothUudHelpers.FromShortId to convert a UINT16 uuid to a 128-bit UUID.

@wind-rider opened an issue [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-uwp/issues/63).

You can use this code snippet:

```
        Guid myGuid = Guid.Parse("34B1CF4D-1069-4AD6-89B6-E161D79BE4D0");

        GattServiceProviderResult result = await GattServiceProvider.CreateAsync(myGuid);

        if (result.Error == BluetoothError.Success)
        {
            serviceProvider = result.ServiceProvider;
        }

        _readCharacteristic = await serviceProvider.Service.CreateCharacteristicAsync(uuid1, ReadParameters);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```cs
GattServiceProviderResult result = await GattServiceProvider.CreateAsync(
            GattServiceUuids.SomeEnumValueDontCopyPaste);
```

or

```cs
GattServiceProviderResult result = await GattServiceProvider.CreateAsync(
            Guid.Parse(someGuid));
```

Create a Characteristic with

```cs
await serviceProvider.Service.CreateCharacteristicAsync(
                GattCharacteristicUuids.SomeEnumValueDontCopyPaste, parameters);
```

or with another `Guid`.

If you want to use `GattLocalCharacteristicParameters`, it should be `StaticValue` instead of `Value` if you want to set a fixed value.

`GattServiceProviderAdvertisingParameters` has properties `IsConnectable` and `IsDiscoverable`

Update: after feedback, Microsoft updated its documentation. Please have a look.